# crash on inserting an object into an array

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

In this code from an array i am selecting a dictionary,modifying it and saving back in another array .but i dont know why at the second last line of this code ie where i am inserting the dict it is crashing (message sent to deallocated instance).how can i fix this

```
        NSArray *array=[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
        NSLog(@"array before %@",array);
        NSMutableArray *tempArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        tempArray=(NSMutableArray*)array;
        NSMutableDictionary *dictToBeChanged=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        dictToBeChanged=[tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [dictToBeChanged setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"isPaid"];
        [tempArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tempArray insertObject:dictToBeChanged atIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"array after %@",tempArray);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign `array` to `tempArray` you don't make it mutable just because you cast it.

It's an `NSArray`, so you can't add/remove its objects.

Also, there are a few unneeded initializations (of tempArray and dictToBeChanged) since you're overwriting those variables with something else right after initializing (thus creating leaks).

What you need is probably something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSMutableDictionary *dictToBeChanged = [[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] mutableCopy] autorelease];
[dictToBeChanged setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"isPaid"];
[array replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:dictToBeChanged];
```

Note that this code doesn't do any validations on the contents of your plist.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add the objects to tempArray as the `temparray` as follows:

```
[tempArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  NSMutableArray *temp;
temp=[temp arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:(NSArray *)otherArray];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at a memory management issue.  Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];//Temp array is unecessary
NSMutableDictionary *dictToBeChanged; //No need to allocate a new instance
```

Not directly related but:

Both of your alloc [init] calls are unnecessary and causing leaks.  Basically what you are doing is creating a new blank array with the allocation and and assigning it to a variable.  Then you immediately assign your variable to another array, losing the reference to the blank array/dictionary you just created, which means it can't get released.  If you are calling release later in your code it will cause trouble.